# I can has(kell) cheezburger?

Tags: beginner, strings, haskell

#### Edit 13 June:

I have made a new and improved version [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/131859/i-can-haskell-moar-cheezburgers).

### Original Question

This is a very rudimentary lolcats translator (it only works on the phrase "Can I have a cheeseburger") in Haskell. This is my first ever attempt at Haskell (or any functional programming language). I am sure that my code is absolutely atrocious (the documentation was dismal) but it works.

#### Teh Codez

```
import Data.Strings
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter your text to translate"
    inputText <- getLine
    let capsText = strToUpper inputText
    let a = strReplace "HAVE" "HAS" capsText
    let b = strReplace "CAN I" "I CAN" a
    let c = strReplace "CHEESEBURGER" "CHEEZBURGER" b
    let d = strReplace " A " " " c
    putStrLn (d)
    getLine
```

Comment: A general rule of thumb in functional programming is to avoid variable assignments (which is basically what `let` is), and instead chain function calls together.  You can see this in the answers below by @200_success and @syb0rg, but neither of them mentioned this idea explicitly.  Variable assignments = mutable state = succeptibility to side effect issues, which is one of the main benefits of a functional language to start with.

Comment: @JamesFaix Mostly true, but Haskell's variables are not mutable as in other languages, so it's mainly a matter of idiomatic style, not safety.

Comment: That `getLine` in the end looks very fishy. Also, no need for parenthesis around the argument to ´putStrLn`.

Comment: @Bergi The `getLine` was to keep the Windows console open after the output was printed. Any other ideas on how to do that?

Comment: @MichaelBrandonMorris: I see. Usually you'd just run your program from the console, so it would stay open anyway.

Comment: @Bergi Okay, but supposing someone runs it via the executable (double click, start menu, etc.) what are my options?

Comment: In this particular case you could just recursively call main at the end of the main function so that your program repeatedly asks for input. Another way to accomplish this is `forever` from Control.Monad

Comment: Should be "haz" ^^

Comment: @Zak Two points, one, "hazkell" would be a bit more of a strech; two, all the translators I have consulted prefer the use of "has" over "haz."

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is good practice in Haskell to separate the functional code from the IO. In this case, you could (and therefore should) define a `lolcat :: String -> String` function.  Be sure to put a type declaration on all functions — you didn't write one for your `main`.

Defining variables `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` is overkill. I would write this as a composition of functions.

```
lolcat :: String -> String
lolcat = strReplace " A " " " .
         strReplace "CHEESEBURGER" "CHEEZBURGER" .
         strReplace "CAN I" "I CAN" .
         strReplace "HAVE" "HAS" .
         strToUpper
```

Comment: I think the difference between this code and the original code in the question does a great job of highlighting the difference between functional and imperative programming styles. A big thing that may be confusing about this is the point-free style: essentially, we are defining a function `lolcat` WITHOUT mentioning the argument of the function -- this might be hard to read at first, but essentially it's the same thing as saying `lolcat(x) = strReplace " A " " " (strReplace "CHEESEBURGER" "CHEEZEBURGER" (... (strToUpper(x))...))`

Comment: Point-free style can be confusing when learning functional programming for the first time coming from an imperative background, but it really is nice/preferable once you get used to it

Comment: I think this is a very good demonstration of point-free style even at a beginner level.

Answer (score 23):

I agree with 200_success and am just typing out the full program because you said you were a beginner.

```
import Data.Strings

encode :: String -> String
encode = strReplace " A " " "
       . strReplace "CHEESEBURGER" "CHEEZBURGER"
       . strReplace "CAN I" "I CAN"
       . strReplace "HAVE" "HAS"
       . strToUpper

main :: IO ()
main = do 
   putStrLn "Enter your text to translate"

   input <- getLine
   putStrLn $ encode input
```

The main function would perhaps more commonly be written as:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   putStrLn "Enter your text to translate"
   putStrLn =<< encode <$> getLine
```

## EDIT:

@MichaelKlein asked me to explain `(<$>)` and `(=<<)`, so I will do so as briefly as possible.

`<$>` is the inline version of `fmap`, which is the only function from the `Functor` typeclass. A typeclass is somewhat like a interface in an imperative language like Java.

```
class Functor f where
   fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

`fmap` is used to run a function `(a -> b)` inside some data structure `f a`

```
fmap (+1) [1]      == [2]
fmap (+1) (Just 3) == Just 4
(+1) <$> (Just 3)  == Just 4

(<$>) :: f a -> ( a -> b ) -> f b
```

In Haskell, we treat the world as a datastructure `IO`. So just in the same way that you can run a function inside a list or a Maybe (like `Just 3`), you can run a function inside a `IO`.

```
encode             :: String -> String
getLine            :: IO String
encode <$> getLine :: IO String
```

`(=<<)` is part of the `Monad` typeclass, [which is hard to explain](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_tutorials_timeline) briefly because you need to know about a few other typeclasses first.

```
(=<<) :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

`(=<<)` is pronounced "bind", and is a flipped version of the more common `(>>=)`. The important bit is that Haskell has a special syntax for working with monads: the `do` notation.

This:

```
main = do
  input <- getLine
  putStrLn input
```

Is syntatic sugar for this:

```
main = getLine >>= \input -> putStrLn input
```

Which is the same as this:

```
main = getLine >>= putStrLn
```

All of these are also equal:

```
main = do
   putStrLn "burger"
   input <- getLine
   putStrLn $ encode input

main = putStrLn "burger" 
    >> getLine >>= \input -> putStrLn $ encode input

main = putStrLn "burger" 
    >> encode <$> getLine >>= putStrLn

main = do 
  putStrLn "burger" 
  putStrLn =<< encode <$> getLine
```

Comment: maybe add the type signatures too `<$> :: f a -> ( a -> b ) -> f b` and `=<< :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b`

Comment: @BlackCap Thanks for adding some explanation. In a case like this, I think it's usually enough to explain what they mean just in the case where you used them here and mention that like `show` they do the same thing, but slightly differently for different types. +1 for going above and beyond.

Answer (score 10):

#### Remove repetition

You repeat a `strReplace` a lot:

```
        vvvvvvvvv
let a = strReplace "HAVE" "HAS" capsText
let b = strReplace "CAN I" "I CAN" a
let c = strReplace "CHEESEBURGER" "CHEEZBURGER" b
let d = strReplace " A " " " c
        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

What changes is what should be replaced by what: `[("HAVE", "HAS"), ("CAN I", "I CAN"), ...]`

Therefore your program  should state the idea of replacement once and then contain this list of "replacement instructions".

To be more clear the function you should use has type `String -> [(String, String)] -> String` and example usage:

```
> replaceByTuples "foobar" [("foo", "fuu"),("bar", "baz")]
"fuubaz"
```

Using this function with your particular list of replacements will be easy.

This function is in this spoiler block. I advise you try to implement it by yourself.

> `import Data.List.Utils;`
>
>
>  `replaceByTuples s t = (foldl (.) id $ map (\(start, end) -> replace start end) t) s`
>  More info and better implementations about this function to be found at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862221/how-do-i-do-string-replace-in-haskell

Comment: I think you should swap the parameters of that `replaceByTuples` function, so that it is more convenient to use curried. Also you could quite trivially implement it by `foldr (uncurry replace)` :-)

Comment: @Bergi Wow, I did not expect such a simple implementation. And yes. ) agree on swapping the arguments.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the other two answers, but I would use `interact` in main. This will make your program infinitely loop until there's no more input which may not be what you want, but it will solve the problem of keeping the console open. You'll have to define an `eachLine` function so that the program processes one line at a time as detailed in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16799891).

As 200_success mentioned, it is good practice to write type-signatures for all top-level functions and `main` traditionally has type-signature: `main :: IO ()`. Because of the `getLine` at the end of your main, it would have type-signature: `main :: IO String`, which would give your program the unintended side-effect of printing an additional string as it terminates. Writing the type-signatures explicitly allows the compiler to catch these sorts of problems.

This would be the full program:

```
import Data.Strings

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter your text to translate"
    interact (eachLine lolcat)

lolcat :: String -> String
lolcat = strReplace " A " " " .
         strReplace "CHEESEBURGER" "CHEEZBURGER" .
         strReplace "CAN I" "I CAN" .
         strReplace "HAVE" "HAS" .
         strToUpper

eachLine :: (String -> String) -> String -> String
eachLine f = unlines . map f . lines
```